# How do I un-indent code?

Tags: notepad++, c++, indentation, geany

I occasionally realise that I need to remove one level of indentation when coding (such as moving code out of loop). The problem is I end up with a bunch of lines all indented more than I want it to be and the only way to indent it the way I want is by manually deleting all the tab spaces.

Is there a way to do this automatically? I use a variety of text editors such as Geany, N++, gedit, and Code::Blocks so I would like a multi-program solution to this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### I need to remove one level of indentation when coding

> I use a variety of text editors such as Geany, N++, gedit, and Code::Blocks

**Notepad++**

Select the lines you want to "unindent" and press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>

**Geany**

Select the lines you want to "unindent" and press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> or  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>

**gedit**

Select the lines you want to "unindent" and press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>

**Codeblocks**

Select the lines you want to "unindent" and press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Also In Visual Studio Code shift+tab will remove one level of indentation.